# Create an email alert for a PySpark job executing on Google Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, dataproc

I am currently working on a PySpark job running on Google Dataproc and need to implement an email alert when. The goal is to receive notifications when specific events or conditions occur during the execution of the PySpark job.

I need to know how to setup the code

Comment: try sending emails using python -- [ref](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.